# How am I rendering more hooks than my previous render?

Tags: reactjs

I have the following code to receive some data from my db, apply some logic and showcase it via recharts. I'm doing lots of logic, so I decided to use useMemo but since I've added the useMemo hook, I've been getting the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.
```

I'm not sure what's going on, but here's my component where the error occurs:

```
import { useGetExpensesQuery, useGetSubCategoriesQuery } from "@/state/api";
import { useMemo } from "react";
import { useCookies } from "react-cookie";
import {
  BarChart,
  Bar,
  XAxis,
  YAxis,
  CartesianGrid,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
  ResponsiveContainer,
} from "recharts";

const BarChartComponent = () => {
  const [cookies] = useCookies(["id"]);
  const { data: expenses, isLoading } = useGetExpensesQuery(cookies.id);
  const { data: subCategories } = useGetSubCategoriesQuery();

  if (!expenses || isLoading) {
    return <p>Loading...</p>;
  }

  const monthNames = [
    "January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December",
  ];

  const newData = useMemo(() => {
    let newData: { date: number }[] = [];
    const months = expenses
      .map((expense) => ({
        ...expense,
        value: expense.price,
        date: new Date(expense.date ?? "").getMonth(),
      }))
      .sort((a, b) => a.date - b.date);
    const reducedMonths = months.reduce(
      (map, { userId, date, price, category, subCategory }) =>
        map.set(date, { ...map.get(date ?? 0), [subCategory]: price }),
      new Map()
    );

    for (let [key, value] of reducedMonths) {
      newData.push({ date: monthNames[key], ...value });
    }
    return newData;
  }, [expenses]);

  const color = [
    "red",
    "purple",
    "blue",
    "orange",
    "green",
    "black",
    "pink",
    "yellow",
  ];

  return (
    <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height="100%">
      <BarChart
        width={500}
        height={300}
        data={newData}
        margin={{
          top: 20,
          right: 30,
          left: 20,
          bottom: 5,
        }}
      >
        <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
        <XAxis dataKey="date" />
        <YAxis />
        <Tooltip />
        <Legend />
        {subCategories?.map(({ name }, idx) => (
          <Bar key={name} dataKey={name} stackId="a" fill={color[idx]} />
        ))}
      </BarChart>
    </ResponsiveContainer>
  );
};

export default BarChartComponent;
```

Comment: Not really, that post just tells me to move the return statement below my useMemo call, doesn't tell me why that fixes it. Also, I need the check to see if expenses isn't null because otherwise I get type issues

Comment: That thread provides perfect explanation for the error you are seeing, and explains how to fix it. Your conditional return statement results in different number of hooks rendered. You can fix this error by moving your return statement below the useMemo hook.

Comment: How would I handle possible undefined type errors for 'expenses' in my useMemo?

Comment: With an `if` statement I guess.